# What will be the difference in output of these 2 MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql

There is a column Salary in a Table EMPLOYEE. The following two statements are giving different outputs. What may be the possible reason?

**Query 1**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT COUNT(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

This question asked in exam but I am not getting any difference even if I left salary of 1 employee blank

Comment: See a full explanation here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: Regarding your edit, blank is **not the same** as NULL.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE` will exclude employees with a salary of NULL.

Comment: No I am getting count as 8 even if I have 1 employee salary as NULL. But when I select that employee salary shows 0

Comment: Then you didn't set it as NULL, or the column's schema doesn't allow NULL values and thusly turns your NULL into a zero.

Comment: YES I got answer
If salary column is defined as NULL and then if any employee's salary is missing then count will skip those null valued record. I got this from http://cbsecsnip.in

Comment: That site is horrendous, and that answer is the same as mine.